# ¿Porque no puedo registrar un cliente en mi api que acabo de crear, en mi archivo db.json?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Acabo de hacer mi propia api y me gustaría registrar pero no pude, solo revisé todo mi código pero no me di cuenta del problema. Aquí está mi código.

App.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

import Inicio from './views/Inicio';
import NuevoCliente from './views/NuevoCliente';
import DetallesCliente from './views/DetallesCliente';

import { DefaultTheme, Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

// Definir el tema
const theme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    primary: '#1774F2',
    accent: '#0655BF'
  }
}



const App  = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <PaperProvider>
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator
              initialRouteName="Inicio"
              screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                  backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary
                },
                headerTintColor: theme.colors.surface, 
                headerTitleStyle: {
                  fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
              }}
            >
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="Inicio"
                  component={Inicio}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="NuevoCliente"
                  component={NuevoCliente}
                  options={{
                    title: "Nuevo Cliente"
                  }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="DetallesCliente"
                  component={DetallesCliente}
                  options={{
                    title: "Detalles Cliente"
                  }}
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </PaperProvider>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  
  
});

export default App;


components/Inicio.js

    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, FlatList, View } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import { List, Headline, Button, FAB } from 'react-native-paper';
import globalStyles from '../styles/global';

const Inicio = ({navigation}) => {

    // state de la app
    const [ clientes, guardarClientes ] = useState([]);
    const [ consultarAPI, guardarConsultarAPI ] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const obtenerClientesApi = async () => {
            try {
                const resultado = await axios.get('http://10.0.2.2:3000/clientes');
                guardarClientes(resultado.data)
                guardarConsultarAPI(false);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }

        if(consultarAPI) {
            obtenerClientesApi();
            
        }
    }, [consultarAPI]);


    return ( 
        <View style={globalStyles.contenedor}>

            <Button icon="plus-circle" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("NuevoCliente", { guardarConsultarAPI }) }>
                Nuevo Cliente
            </Button>

            <Headline style={globalStyles.titulo}> { clientes.length > 0 ? "Clientes" : "Aún no hay Clientes" } </Headline>

            <FlatList
                data={clientes}
                keyExtractor={ cliente => (cliente.id).toString()  }
                renderItem={ ({item}) => (
                    <List.Item
                        title={item.nombre}
                        description={item.empresa}
                        onPress={ () => navigation.navigate("DetallesCliente", { item, guardarConsultarAPI }) }
                    />
                )}
            />

            <FAB
                icon="plus"
                style={globalStyles.fab}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("NuevoCliente", { guardarConsultarAPI }) }
            />
        </View>
     );
}

 
export default Inicio;
```

components/DetallesCliente.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { Headline, Text, Subheading, Button, FAB } from 'react-native-paper';
import globalStyles from '../styles/global';
import axios from 'axios';


const DetallesCliente = ({navigation, route}) => {
    const { guardarConsultarAPI  } = route.params;
    const { nombre, telefono, correo, empresa, id } = route.params.item;

    const mostrarConfirmacion = () => {
        Alert.alert(
            '¿Deseas eliminar este cliente?',
            'Un contacto eliminado no se puede recuperar',
            [
                { text: 'Si, Eliminar', onPress: () => eliminarContacto() },
                { text: 'Cancelar', style: 'cancel' }
            ]
        )
    }

    const eliminarContacto = async () => {
        const url = `http://10.0.2.2:3000/clientes/${id}`;
        // console.log(url);
        try {
            await axios.delete(url);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

        // Redireccionar
        navigation.navigate('Inicio');

        // volver a consultar la api
        guardarConsultarAPI(true);
    }

    return ( 
        <View style={globalStyles.contenedor}>
            <Headline style={globalStyles.titulo}>{nombre}</Headline>
            <Text style={styles.texto}>Empresa: <Subheading>{empresa}</Subheading> </Text> 
            <Text style={styles.texto}>Correo: <Subheading>{correo}</Subheading> </Text> 
            <Text style={styles.texto}>Teléfono: <Subheading>{telefono}</Subheading> </Text> 

            <Button 
                style={styles.boton} 
                mode="contained" 
                icon="cancel"
                onPress={ () => mostrarConfirmacion()  }
            >
                Eliminar Cliente
            </Button>

            <FAB
                icon="pencil"
                style={globalStyles.fab}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("NuevoCliente", { cliente: route.params.item,  guardarConsultarAPI }) }
            />
        </View>
     );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    texto: {
        marginBottom: 20,
        fontSize:18
    },
    boton: {
        marginTop: 100,
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
})
 
export default DetallesCliente;
```

components/NuevoCliente.js

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native';

import { TextInput, Headline, Button, Paragraph, Dialog, Portal } from 'react-native-paper';
import globalStyles from '../styles/global';
import axios from 'axios';

const NuevoCliente = ({navigation, route}) => {

    const { guardarConsultarAPI } = route.params;

    // campos formulario
    const [ nombre, guardarNombre] = useState('');
    const [ telefono, guardarTelefono] = useState('');
    const [ correo, guardarCorreo] = useState('');
    const [ empresa, guardarEmpresa] = useState('');
    const [ alerta, guardarAlerta] = useState(false);

    // detectar si estamos editando o no
    useEffect(() => {
        if(route.params.cliente) {
            const { nombre, telefono, correo, empresa } = route.params.cliente;

            guardarNombre(nombre);
            guardarTelefono(telefono);
            guardarCorreo(correo);
            guardarEmpresa(empresa);
        } 
    }, []);

    // almacena el cliente en la BD
    const guardarCliente = async () => {
        // validar
        if(nombre === '' || telefono === '' || correo === '' || empresa === '' ) {
            guardarAlerta(true)
            return;
        }
    
        // generar el cliente
        const cliente = { nombre, telefono, empresa, correo };
        console.log(cliente);

        // Si estamos editando o creando un nuevo cliente
        if(route.params.cliente) {

            const { id } = route.params.cliente;
            cliente.id = id;
            const url = `http://10.0.2.2:3000/clientes${id}`;

            try {
                await axios.put(url, cliente);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }

        } else {
            // guardar el cliente en la API
            try {
                if(Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                    await axios.post('http://10.0.2.2:8081/clientes', cliente)
                } else {
                    await axios.post('http://10.0.2.2:3000/clientes', cliente);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }

        // redireccionar
        navigation.navigate('Inicio');

        // limpiar el form (opcional)
        guardarNombre('');
        guardarTelefono('');
        guardarCorreo('');
        guardarEmpresa('');

        // cambiar a true para traernos el nuevo cliente
        guardarConsultarAPI(true);
    }

    return ( 
        <View style={globalStyles.contenedor}>

            <Headline style={globalStyles.titulo}>Añadir Nuevo Cliente</Headline>

            <TextInput
                label="Nombre"
                placeholder="Juan"
                onChangeText={ texto => guardarNombre(texto) }
                value={nombre}
                style={styles.input}
            />
            <TextInput
                label="Teléfono"
                placeholder="13131414"
                onChangeText={ texto => guardarTelefono(texto) }
                value={telefono}
                style={styles.input}
            />
            <TextInput
                label="Correo"
                placeholder="correo@correo.com"
                onChangeText={ texto => guardarCorreo(texto) }
                value={correo}
                style={styles.input}
            />
            <TextInput
                label="Empresa"
                placeholder="Nombre Empresa"
                onChangeText={ texto => guardarEmpresa(texto) }
                value={empresa}
                style={styles.input}
            />

            <Button icon="pencil-circle" mode="contained" onPress={() => guardarCliente() }>
                Guardar Cliente
            </Button>

            <Portal>
                <Dialog
                    visible={alerta}
                    onDismiss={ () => guardarAlerta(false) }
                 >
                   <Dialog.Title>Error</Dialog.Title>
                   <Dialog.Content>
                        <Paragraph>Todos los campos son obligatorios</Paragraph>
                   </Dialog.Content>
                   <Dialog.Actions>
                       <Button onPress={ () => guardarAlerta(false) }>OK</Button>
                   </Dialog.Actions>
                </Dialog>
            </Portal>
             
        </View>
     );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    input: {
        marginBottom: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    }
})
 
export default NuevoCliente;
```

Intente registrar en un archivo json, que es el que esta relacionado con la api

db.json

```
   {
  "clientes": [{}]
}
```

Todas las cosas que hago en esta aplicación, es solo crear mi propia api, y luego tengo tres pantallas, Inicio, DetallesCliente, NuevoCliente. En la pagina de Inicio, estan todos los clientes que registro desde el formulario que es la otra pagina, luego de registrar un cliente en la pagina de NuevoCliente, me manda de esa pagina a la pagina de Inicio, haciendo una consulta desde la api, al archivo db .json, si haces clic en un cliente, puedes eliminarlo, si quieres o editarlo, tienes un botón que dice cancelar y ese botón te redirige a la página de inicio, pero el problema aquí es cuando intento registrar un cliente desde la primera vez desde la página de NuevoCliente me redirige a la página de Inicio pero aparentemente no se registra, porque no me muestra nada. Realmente agradecería si pudiera ayudar con este problema gracias

Comment: El titulo tambien por favor.. que cosa no podes registrar?

Comment: Un cliente, cree una api, en la cual registro un cliente, pero no me registra, aparentemente lo que tengo mal es la url que aparece en el archivo de NuevoCliente

Comment: Y en que url esta tu backend?